# Unzip and decrypted incoming message - NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, xml, encryption, unzip

I am currently working on a project that takes incoming messages from Amazons SQS (Simple Queue Service).

I have established the connection to the SQS service and receiving messages.

The receiving message is in the following format:

```
    { MessageId: '124a42b-657d-481d-348f-ddd9b8d8b143b',
  ReceiptHandle: 'AQEBSSVzlCbqsSUQ3E.....',
  MD5OfBody: '7ba46c7c8874fc6d0c4a141a2d3d4d5a721',
  Body: '10987235@PUBLISH;aSeIgjS78Iy4KRZHSeAy43...' }
```

The Body of the message is zipped and encrypted.

My question is what is the best way to decrypt and unzip the message Body? Currently I am writing the message.Body to a file and trying to decrypt and extract form the file. Here is a copy of my code:

```
const Consumer = require('sqs-consumer');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require("path");
const unzipper = require('unzipper');

const app = Consumer.create({
  queueUrl: 'https://sqs.us-west-1.amazonaws.com/QueueName',
  handleMessage: (message, done) => {

    saveToFile(message.Body)
      .then(() => {
        return unzipFile();
      })
      .then((success) => {
        // read content of XML file and save to DB
        console.log('success:', success);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        console.log('Error:', e);
      });

  },
  sqs: new AWS.SQS()
});

app.on('error', (err) => {
  console.log(err.message);
});

app.start();


const saveToFile = (message) => {
  debugger;
  console.log('saveToFile fired!');
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.appendFile(path.resolve(__dirname) + '/zips/decodeMsg.zip', message, (err) => {
      if (err) reject(error);
      resolve();
    });
  });
}

const unzipFile = () => {
  return unzipper.Open.file(path.resolve(__dirname) + '/zips/decodeMsg.zip') // Fails To Read The File Here.
    .then(function (directory) {
      console.log('directory', directory);
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        directory.files[0].stream(password)  // PASSING IN PASSWORD HERE
          .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('readablefile')) // should be XML
          .on('error', reject)
          .on('finish', resolve)
      });
    });
}
```

At this point when unzipFile() is invoked and a error is returned:

```
Error: Uncaught, unspecified "error" event. (FILE_ENDED)
at PullStream.emit (events.js:163:17)
at PullStream.onerror (_stream_readable.js:579:12)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
at PullStream.emit (events.js:188:7)
```

My question is should I even be writing the message Body to a file and trying to extract and decrypt it, or is there a better way to do this?

Any input is much appreciated.

Comment: You should pass it as a stream instead of writing to disk.

Comment: And you probably need to decrypt it first.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks man, could you give me an example?